# Google Android Mobile Vision - How to read Ean13 with addon (5 and 2 chars length)?

Tags: android, kotlin, decode, barcode, add-on

I'm working with Android Mobile Vision to decode barcodes from a Bitmap (in Kotlin) and it works perfectly with all barcodes.

I need to decode, from images, EAN13 and EAN8 barcodes with EAN5 and EAN2 addons like this

[Barcode Ean13+5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpuEY.jpg)

Is it possible to decode it as a single barcode (978125958933156000)?
Even with 2 readings could be good for me (ean13: 9781259589331 and ean5: 56000).

Thanks for every bit of info you could provide.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to my question here

[Can't read EAN Type Barcode](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/339)

Consequently I will search for another library to decode ean13 and ean8 barcodes with supplements.